# How to let my log in page normally show up?

Tags: grub2

I use a server board to run Ubuntu 20.04.2.

After i installed BMC and BIOS, I chose ubuntu to run.

In Ubuntu, I started to open terminal and type `apt-get update`、`apt-get upgrade`.

When the upgrade over, I started to reboot.

I found out the log in page was black screen.

What i first to do is to google how to let log in page show up.

I found that use vim to edit `/etc/default/grub`and add  `nomodeset`in`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”`becamed
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash nomodeset”`.

So i typed `sudo update-grub`and`sudo reboot`, the log in page showed up.

But it looked strange. The log in page is much bigger than normal size.

My server Main board is `X570D4I-2T`. It does not need a graphic card.

It used `ASPEED AST2500` controller.

This controller use VGA Drivers.

Is there another way to let log in page become normal and show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its regarding resolution of Login screen as you have got sucess for bringing the screen try this :

The first thing to do is to check resolution setup in grub. To do that reboot your computer and hit Esc repeatedly until you get the purple screen with the recovery and grub options. Hit "c" to get a grub prompt. At the grub prompt, type:

> videoinfo

and hit Enter.

Look at the list of "supported" resolutions, and make sure x*y (resolution of your system) is there. If so, type:

> exit

to exit grub and boot.

The boot screen resolution is changed by changing your default grub settings. Open a terminal and enter:

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Use the down arrow or Page Down until you see the line that looks like this:

> #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

Below that line, enter the following, substituting the x*y(your display resolution) for a supported resolution:

For example:

> GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080

> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

To save your changes, hit Ctrl+o, with "o" as in orange, not zero. To exit nano, hit Ctrl+x. Now, update grub:

> sudo update-grub

Comment: Thanks for the answer.After adding resolution and keeping "nomodeset" on grub.It looks normal